# JavaFX: Menu items only shown as three dots when in BorderPane

Tags: javafx, menubar, borderpane

I am trying to learn JavaFX and I've run into a problem with the `Menus` in my `MenuBar`. Here is a minimal example:

```
public void start(Stage mainStage) throws Exception {
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 1000, Color.WHITE);
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    Menu menuFile = new Menu("_File");
    menuBar.getMenus().add(menuFile);
    MenuItem add = new MenuItem("_New");
    menuFile.getItems().add(add);
    root.getChildren().add(menuBar);
    menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(mainStage.widthProperty());
    mainStage.setScene(scene);
    mainStage.show();
}
```

This application starts, but the `Menu` in the `MenuBar` is only shown as three dots (...). It does open however when I press `ALT+F`, so it is there.

From what I understand, a `Menu` item has no `width` or similar attribute, so that can't be set. I suspect it has something to do with my root node being a `BorderPane`, because in every other example I found that works, the root is either a `VBox` or something else. I seem to get the desired results when I place a `Vbox` as my root node, and then add the `MenuBar` and the BorderPane` to the root - but that seems like a strange and uneccesary workaround to me.

So what am I missing here? Is it true that a `MenuBar` will only ever look like it should in certain containers? What is the difference between a `BorderPane` and a `VBox` in this regard? If someone could explain or point me to a part of the documentation that I've missed, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `BorderPane` and using `getChildren().add()` to add MenuBar in it, which is incorrect. `BorderPane` unlike `VBox`, can't accept any number of children and is divided into 5 specific positions :

- top
- left
- right
- bottom
- center

The children goes into any one of these positions. [Please go through the documentation for BorderPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html).

You need to add the Menubar to the top of the BorderPane using :

```
root.setTop(menuBar);
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! It sounds very reasonable. I couln't figure that out myself just from the documentation because I am too inexperienced, I guess.